# How does Rubygem require all gems?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I got interested in Rubygem, and started to explore how does it works, and found out that after 1.9, Rubygem's `require` became THE `require`.

With the code below:

```
require 'debugger'
debugger
require 'thor'
```

I started to `n` and `l` and `s`, but got stuck at:

```
  # specification.rb:263
  def self._all # :nodoc:
    unless defined?(@@all) && @@all then
      specs = {}

      self.dirs.each { |dir|
        Dir[File.join(dir, "*.gemspec")].each { |path|
          spec = Gem::Specification.load path.untaint
          # #load returns nil if the spec is bad, so we just ignore
          # it at this stage
          specs[spec.full_name] ||= spec if spec
        }
      }

      @@all = specs.values

      _resort!
    end
    @@all
  end
```

It seems that before stepping into the method above, `@@all` has already be been prepared. Then I set break-points everywhere `@@all =`, but none of the break-points are reached.

What am i missing???

---

**EDIT:**

Look at my question again. See `require 'debugger'`? I feel like a fool.

Now the question is **"How can I debug `require`"**?

---

**CLOSED:**

Plz see this great answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/16069229/342366

Comment: What do you mean by «I started to `n` && `l` && `s`»? And where is `self._all` coming from?

Comment: I tried to clarify your question, if that is not ok with you, help yourself...

Comment: @BeatRichartz n&&l&&s == next&&list&&step,commands in debugger

Comment: "next&&list&&step" then please spell those out. Using your own shorthand only confuses people who don't understand it. Remember that Stack Overflow is visited by people around the world.

Comment: If the question has changed then please open a new one. The title and body of your question have little to do with "How can I debug `require`", and that question deserves its own space.

Comment: maybe put a require "debugger"; debugger within the unless defined? block?

Answer (score 0):

Thx again for this greet answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/16069229/342366, i did a little debugging myself.

For some one google to this question(and lazy to debug), i decide to post the answer to "How does Rubygem require all gems?"

There are the key-steps below:

1. load all ".gemspec" in "Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\specifications"

   ```
   Dir[File.join(dir, "*.gemspec")].each { |path|
     spec = Gem::Specification.load path.untaint
     # #load returns nil if the spec is bad, so we just ignore
     # it at this stage
     specs[spec.full_name] ||= spec if spec
   }
   ```
2. sort the gems by version desc

   ```
   @@all.sort! { |a, b|
     names = a.name <=> b.name
     next names if names.nonzero?
     b.version <=> a.version
   }
   ```
3. got the first gem (the higher version)

   ```
   self.find { |spec|
     spec.contains_requirable_file? path
   }
   ```
4. activate the gem and all dependencies~ Everyone's happy.