# How can I debug require in Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby, rubygems

According to `the Tin Man`'s opinion, i open a new question.

Original questions is here: [How does Rubygem require all gems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16063144/342366)

Original code i used to debug:

```
require 'debugger'
debugger
require 'thor'
```

Here's the dilemma:

1. debug with the default `-rdebug`, i cant go to Rubygem's source code
2. debug with `debugger` gem, i have to `require` before i debug (the way i tried in the previous question, which is unacceptable because something important had happened before i get there)

Hope to find a way to debug IT.

Comment: Can you please make a little example of the code you want to debug?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063144/how-does-rubygem-require-all-gems @ProGNOMmers

Comment: since this answer is different from the other one, you could copy the code related to this answer here, so the understanding of this answer doesn't depend from the other one :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `rubygems` is required it [replaces Ruby’s `Kernel.require` method with its own that searches for required files in the installed gems](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_9_3_392/lib/rubygems/custom_require.rb#L21-34). The integration with Ruby 1.9 and above is basically a [call to `require 'rubygems'` during start up](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_9_3_392/ruby.c#L1374). This can be disabled with the (poorly documented) `--disable-gems` option to the `ruby` executable. You could make use of this to set up your debugging before explicitly calling `require 'rubygems'`.

```ruby
# start with ruby --disable-gems
require 'debug' #standard library debug - doesn't load rubygems

require 'rubygems' #now you can debug this
```

If you want to use the [`debugger` gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/debugger) for your debugging it’s still possible but a little trickier as you have to load `debugger` without loading Rubygems. In order to do this you’ll need to manually set up your load path to include Debugger’s lib dir, as well as the lib dirs of any gems Debugger depends on. This is basically what Rubygems does for you when you call `require 'debugger'` with Rubygems loaded.

To determine what libs Debugger needs, you can use this command:

```
 ruby -e "lp = $:.dup; gem 'debugger'; puts $: - lp"
```

This is little Ruby script that first takes a copy of the load path (`$:` is the load path, you can also use `$LOAD_PATH`), then activates the Debugger gem, then prints out the difference between the new load path and the original. This will give you the dirs that activating `debugger` adds to the load path.

On my machine this looks like this:

```
$ ruby -e "lp = $:.dup; gem 'debugger'; puts $: - lp"
/Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/columnize-0.3.6/lib
/Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/debugger-ruby_core_source-1.2.0/lib
/Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/debugger-linecache-1.2.0/lib
/Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/debugger-1.5.0/lib
```

You can now use this to create a script to use Debugger to debug `require 'rubygems'`:

```ruby
# start with ruby --disable-gems

# set up the load path without loading rubygems
$:.unshift '/Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/columnize-0.3.6/lib'
$:.unshift '/Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/debugger-ruby_core_source-1.2.0/lib'
$:.unshift '/Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/debugger-linecache-1.2.0/lib'
$:.unshift '/Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/debugger-1.5.0/lib'

# require debugger and start it
require 'debugger'
debugger

require "rubygems" #now you can debug this with debugger
```